# XAML apply gradient fade effect to content of container

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

Is there are way in **XAML** to have all of the content of a container gradually fade? For example, imagine we have a `<StackPanel>` and it contains several `<TextBlock>` elements...I want all of their `.Foreground` values to take on the applied gradient.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Tue" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Wed" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Thu" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Fri" />
     </StackPanel>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock Text="Sat" />
     </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

I would like the text-block's text values to fade from white at the top, down to transparent. I do **not** want to apply a `<LinearGradientBrush>` to each individual `<TextBlock.Foreground>`, nor do I want to apply a `.Background` gradient.

Answer (score 1):

If text is all you need, then the [Foreground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.foreground?view=winrt-22621) property is a `Brush` type, meaning we can simply apply a gradient brush to any Control or TextBlock:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dolor.">
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Offset="0.8" Color="#000000" />
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

Which gives you:

[image: A rendered text block with a fade effect]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, however as everything nowadays you can fake it as long as there is no picture as background, but a bindable color. You can create a rectangle which will overlap your current stack panel and you can bind your background color and use it as to fake transperent controls. Here is a sample how you can do it.

```
  <Page
    x:Class="App1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dolor." />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dolor." />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dolor." />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dolor." />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque dolor." />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0.5,0.5">
                    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent" />
                    <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="White" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Other alternative would be to use converter but you have to apply the same converter to every control. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

Isn't that what you want or I don't understand the question?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, it simply draws a gradient rectangle over my text.

Comment: Dark theme, black back ground with white foreground for the text. Does that way work?

Comment: I didn't gave it much of a tought at first, but I guess it won't work because you will have a visible transition line.